# R: how to rank longitudinal data

Tags: r, ranking

```
> dput(subset)
structure(list(MEMORY1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), MEMORY2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MEMORY3 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MEMORY4 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MEMORY5 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), MEMORY6 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), MEMORY7 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), MEMORY8 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("MEMORY1", "MEMORY2", "MEMORY3", 
"MEMORY4", "MEMORY5", "MEMORY6", "MEMORY7", "MEMORY8"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

> subset
  MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
1       1       1       1       2       1       1       2       1
2       1       1       2       2       2       1       2       1
3       1       1       1       2       1       2       2       1
4       1       1       1       2       2       1       2       1
5       2       1       1       2       1       2       1       1
```

My data has 8 items (columns) recorded at 5 time intervals (rows). I would like to rank the data as follows: 1) if column has all 1s, then the column gets rank 8. 2) rank of the column is dependent upon when a number greater than 1 first appears (for MEMORY1 it would be 5, MEMORY3 is 2, MEMORY4 is 1, and so forth). I wrote the following loop to do this.

```
ranks = rep(0, 8)
for(i in 1:8){
  v = which(subset[i] > 1)
  if(length(v) == 0){
    ranks[i] = 8
  }else ranks[i] = v[1]
}
> ranks
[1] 5 8 2 1 2 3 1 8
```

Works fine but I realized that since there are ties, i.e, MEMORY4 and MEMORY7 are both ranked as 1, then I would want MEMORY3 and MEMORY5 to be ranked as 3 instead of 2. In that case MEMORY6 should be ranked as 5, not 3. So the desired ranking should be.

`6 8 3 1 3 5 1 8`

Comment: It is `3` in `ranks`; unless you're referring to what my desired ranking should be?

Comment: I think posing a question that is verging on being incoherent and then has an incorrect "answer" is not useful.

Comment: This is a really odd `rank`ing. It's a min rank, with a max rank at one end. Maybe something like `rank(sapply(data.frame(rbind(dat > 1, TRUE)),which.max),ties.method="min")` would make more sense than artificially inflating the last ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to loop through the columns of 'df1' using `sapply` and get the first position where the value is greater than 1.  If there are no values that are greater than 1, it will be `NA`.  Then, we get the `rank` of the 'indx' specifying the `ties.method` as `min` ('indx1').  The position of NA values in 'indx' is replaced by 8 as the last step.

```
 indx <- sapply(df1, function(x) which(x>1)[1L])
 indx1 <- as.vector(rank(indx, ties.method='min'))
 indx1[is.na(indx)] <- 8
 indx1
 #[1] 6 8 3 1 3 5 1 8
```